# Particle systems don't start unless I look at them (Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I'm currently working on an atmospheric system in Unity (day/night cycle, weather). I'm having an issue where my rain/snow particle systems won't start unless I look at them. They're way up in the sky, so the chances of a player looking at the particle system exactly in time with when the rain would start are very slim. Plus, there would be sound desync.

Yesterday I just had the particle system play on awake and realized that nothing would happen if I didn't look at them. I dismissed the thought, thinking that once I hooked them up to a script they would play when told to. Unfortunately, that's not the case.

I can provide code if need be, but I don't see how it could be necessary. If you need any extra details, I'd be glad to supply them. Thanks in advance.